# Entity Framework Power Shell commands do not work after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, powershell

In Visual Studio 2013, after upgrading to Windows 10, I got the message some NuGet packages were missing, would you like to restore. After the restore when I issue the Entity Framework command 'Update-Database' in the Package Manager console I get the following error:

```
PM> Update-Database 
Update-Database : The term 'Update-Database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

I killed the package directory and allowed the packages to re-download but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot the computer. Sad answer, but it fixed the problem.